# i met problem with my shopping card in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

> this is App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ListProduct from "./listProduct";
import ListOrder from "./listOrder";
import pizza from "./pizza.jpg";
import './style.css'
import { Container,Row,Col,Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
      count: 0,
      products: [
        { id: 0, name: "Cold cuts", price: 5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 1, name: "Pepperoni", price: 3.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 2, name: "Feta", price: 2.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 3, name: "Mozzarella", price: 1.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 4, name: "Swiss cheese", price: 1.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 5, name: "Spices", price: 0.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 6, name: "Vegetable", price: 0.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
      ],
      foodsOrder: [],
    };
  }
  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Container >
        <Row>
          <Col xs = {8}>
              <ListOrder />
          </Col>
          <Col className = 'item'>
            <Row className = 'header'>
              <span>Your pizza : </span>
              <span>$</span>
              <Button variant = 'warning'>Reset Pizza</Button>
            </Row>
            <ListProduct
              count={this.state.count}
              handleIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
              products = {this.state.products}
            />
          </Col>  
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

> this is listProduct.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Item from "./Item";
import {Row,Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
class ListProduct extends React.Component {
    render() {
    const {handleIncrement,count,products} = this.props
    return (
      <>

       {products.map(product =>  <Item key = {`${product.id}`} {...product}
          handleIncrement={handleIncrement}
          count={count}
        />)
       }
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default ListProduct;
```

> this is Item.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ListProduct from './listProduct';
import {Row,Col,Button,Badge } from 'react-bootstrap';
class Item extends React.Component{
    render(){
            const {id,name,price,value,pizza} = this.props
            const {handleIncrement,count} = this.props
        return (
        <>
        <Row className = 'item'>
            <Col className = 'information'>
                <p>{name}</p>
                <p>{`${price} $`}</p>   
            </Col>
            <Col className = 'button'>
                <Button className = 'add' variant = 'success' onClick = {() => {handleIncrement(id)}} >+</Button>
                <Badge>{count}</Badge>
                <Button className = 'delete' variant="danger">-</Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        </>
        )
    }
}
export default Item;
```

> when i click event hanldeInCrement in button , all variable this.state.count in class App increase as picture follow . i'm try orther way but doesn't 
>   [image]
>
> i want to when i click button that just only focus button executing.
>   Help me. Thank you so much........................................

Comment: What's the issue? Can you clarify?

Comment: when i click event hanldeIncrement in button , that just only this button increase variable count

Answer (score 0):

You're only storing one single count of the products. Since the state is stored in the `App` component, you only have one single count. The state is one global object, and is not independent for each product on the list. You will either need to store a list of counts in the `App` component and update them like that, or give each list item its own state to keep track of its own count.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `count` as total.

I think it is NOT what you want.

If you want to count up each product, you should separate the count to each product.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
      count: 0,  // I think it doesn't need.
      products: [
        { id: 0, count: 0, name: "Cold cuts", price: 5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 1, count: 0, name: "Pepperoni", price: 3.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 2, count: 0, name: "Feta", price: 2.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 3, count: 0, name: "Mozzarella", price: 1.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 4, count: 0, name: "Swiss cheese", price: 1.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 5, count: 0, name: "Spices", price: 0.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
        { id: 6, count: 0, name: "Vegetable", price: 0.5, value: 0, src: pizza },
      ],
      foodsOrder: [],
    };
  }
```

And you should change your `Increase` function.

```
handleIncrement = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    products: this.state.products.map((item) => item.id === id ? {...item, count:item.count+1} : {...item});
  });
}
```

> You can use the `value` attribute as a product's count, It looks better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the same state.count for all your products. Have you tried adding count to the objects in state.products? the only prob you would need to pass is the products.